# Prove $ \exists c \in [0,1]: \int_{0}^{1}\sin(x^3)dx = \int_{0}^{c}\sin(x^2)dx $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Prove

$$
\exists c \in [0,1]: \int_{0}^{1}\sin(x^3)dx = \int_{0}^{c}\sin(x^2)dx
$$

### What i tried to do:

$$
\sin(x^3) \leq \sin(x^2), \forall x \in [1,0]
$$

Therefore

$$
\int_{0}^{1} \sin(x^3) \leq \int_{0}^{1} \sin(x^2) 
$$

I though maybe to use mean value integral:

$$
\frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b}f(x) dx = f(c)
$$

$f$ is continous as a sin function in the interval $[1,0]$ therefore, we can write for $c \in [1,0]$:

$$
\int_{0}^{1}\sin(x^3) dx = \sin(c^3)
$$

It seems to me the right way but i am stuck.

Is it the right way? Can i have a hint?

Answer (score 5):

Intermediate value theorem would be the way to go. Define the antiderivative starting at $0$ by

$$F(t) \equiv \int_0^t\sin(x^2)\:dx$$

We have that $F(0) = 0$ and from your reasoning above that

$$F(1) = \int_0^1 \sin(x^2)\:dx \geq \int_0^1 \sin(x^3)\:dx$$

Establish the continuity of $F(t)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: So because its contiunous function, $F$, in that interval, gets any value between $F(1)$ and $F(0)$. We know that $F(0) = 0$ and $\int_{0}^{1}sin(x^3)$ is a positive value between $[F(0), F(1)]$ (concluded from what you wrote about $F[1]$) therefore $\exists c \in [0,1]$ such that $F(c) = \int_{0}^{c}sin(x^2) = \int_{0}^{1}sin(x^3)$

Comment: @Alon exactly! Can you prove it is continuous though? You can only use the intermediate value theorem if you can establish that fact.

Comment: @NinadMunshi $F$ is differentiable, hence continuous ;)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen exactly! But OP needs to be able to come up with this reasoning on their own

Comment: One can directly use the theorem that any integral function $F$ given by $F(x) =\int_{a} ^{x} f(t) \, dt$ is continuous if the integral for $f$ is defined over $[a, b] $. This is true for Lebesgue integrals as well.

Answer (score 3):

Let $g(x)=\int_0^{x} \sin (y^{2})dy$. Then $g$ is a continuous function. Hence it assumes all values between $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=\int_0^{1} \sin (y^{2})dy$. It remains only to show that $\int_0^{1} \sin (x^{3})dx$ is  a number between these two values. But this is true since $0 \leq \int_0^{1} \sin (x^{3})dx \leq \int_0^{1} \sin (x^{2})dx$

Comment: Thank you also for the help